# Algorithm Package Error in Beamer

Tags: beamer, algorithmicx

I have the following trivial example that I just can't compile.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme[RGB={0,0,0}]{structure}
}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,graphicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{tikz, nth}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Function{deleteMax}{}{
\State{$P \gets$ \Call{Skip-Search}{$L$, Max}}
}
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This produces the error

> ! Missing \endcsname inserted.  \ALG@currentblock@2

that I just can't get rid of. Strangely enough, if I add an if statement, I do not get an error.

Note: I can put any amount of `\State` statements without the \Function body, so the error seems to be related to that somehow.

Comment: Removing the extra set of brackets seems to fix the issue, but I do not know why. I have other examples with these brackets there, and they do not cause an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is your interpretation of the macros involved with the `algorithmic` construction. The `\State` macro doesn't take an argument. So, use

```
\State <state content>
```

and not

```
\State{<state content>}
```

In a similar way, you think `\Function` takes three arguments, the last of which is the body of the function. This is not true, as the start and end of the function are given by `\Function` and `\EndFunction`, respectively (see section **3.1.6. the function block** of the [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf)). So, use

```
\Function{<name>}{<parms>}
  <body>
\EndFunction
```

and not

```
\Function{<name>}{<parms>}{
  <body>
}
\EndFunction
```

Here is a minimal example that provides what I described above:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \Function{deleteMax}{}
      \State $P \gets$ \Call{Skip-Search}{$L$, Max}
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```